# How can I get a list of the System Tray notifications in Python?

Tags: python, windows, system-tray

[System Tray Notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOmFd.png)

I would like to get a list of the System Tray notifications in Python.

I've spent some decent time googling and there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented way to get a list of notification icons.

[TraySaver](https://sourceforge.net/projects/traysaver/) did it 20 years ago but that code is unlikely to work on recent versions of Windows. Any attempt to access this list is going to be filled with ugly hacks and crashes...

You can probably use [UI Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) for the icons that are visible but it will probably not work when the overflow list is hidden.